# NoReverseMatch pattern not found

Tags: python, django

Having trouble figuring out why I keep getting the `NoReverseMatch`.

**app/url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns

from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<contact_id>\d+)/detail/$', views.details, name='details'),


)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import Http404
from django.views import generic

from django.template import RequestContext, loader

from .models import Person
# Create your views here.


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'ContactManager/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'contact_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Person.objects.order_by('lname')


def details(request, contact_id):
    contact = get_object_or_404(Person, id=contact_id)
    return render(request, 'ContactManager/details.html', {'contact': contact})

# class DetailView(generic.ListView):
#     model = Person
#     context_object_name = 'contact'
#     template_name = 'ContactManager/details.html'
#
#     def get_queryset(self):
#
```

**template index.html**

```
{% if contact_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for contact in contact_list %}
            <li>
               <a href="{% url 'contact:details' contact_id=contact.id %}"> {{ contact.fname }} &nbsp; {{ contact.lname }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>You don't have any contacts currently.</p>
{% endif %}
```

The error I am getting:

```
Reverse for 'details' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'contact_id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$(?P<contact_id>\\d+)/detail/$']
```

I have tried using generic views and a host of arguments in the `{% url ... %}`
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, it should be views.py. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: did you add `namespace='contacts` in main `urls.py` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that details url pattern has a mistake, in error message appears one tried pattern, started and ended by `$` sign:

> 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$(?P\d+)/detail/$']

check your pattern that is equal to or no:

```
^(?P<contact_id>\\d+)/detail/$
```

if this is correct check your urls file that included contact urls and if is similar below:

```
url('^$', include(ContactManager.urls, namespace='contact'))
```

remove `$` sign at end of prefix-pattern:

```
url('^', include(ContactManager.urls, namespace='contact'))
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. I messed up the url in the project/url.py

I had:
url(r'^$', include('ContactManager.urls', namespace='contact')),

instead of the correct way:
url(r'^', include('ContactManager.urls', namespace='contact')),

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Note that this error can also arise if you do not define `name` in your `urlpatterns`.

Doing something like

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^error_containing_view/$', views.error_containing_view, name='error_containing_view'),
]
```

in your app's urls.py would fix the error.